# passing variables in a function to the external function - php

Tags: php, function, variables

There are three functions.  Two of the functions uses some variables exactly the same way so I created a third function but the variables aren't able to be passed into those two functions.

**EDIT**
What I need in more detail.  Two functions are identical search() and report() but of course there will be differences too.

search()

```
public function search(){
    if(($_POST['number'] != null) && (is_numeric($_POST['number']))){
        $number = trim($_POST['number']);
    }else{
        $number = "";
    }

    if (($_POST['name'] != null)) {
        $name = strtoupper(trim($_POST['name']));
    }else{
        $comments = "";
    }

    if($_POST['date'] != null){
        $date = trim($_POST['date']);
        $parseDate = explode("/", $date);
        $newDate = $parseDate[2].$parseDate[0].$parseDate[1];
    }else{
        $newDate = null;
    }

    //something will be done here//
    //will require using all 3 of the variables above
}
```

report()

```
  public function report(){
    if(($_POST['number'] != null) && (is_numeric($_POST['number']))){
        $number = trim($_POST['number']);
    }else{
        $number = "";
    }

    if (($_POST['name'] != null)) {
        $name = strtoupper(trim($_POST['name']));
    }else{
        $comments = "";
    }

    if($_POST['date'] != null){
        $date = trim($_POST['date']);
        $parseDate = explode("/", $date);
        $newDate = $parseDate[2].$parseDate[0].$parseDate[1];
    }else{
        $newDate = null;
    }

    //something will be done here//
    //will require using all 3 of the variables above
}
```

combine()

```
public function combine(){
    //as can be seen.  The above two functions are totally the same but after that where I commented "something will be done here" different things would be done with different output.
}
```

`search()` and `report()` will end up using json_encode to pass some data back to the client side.

Comment: In functions use `$this->a = 'a';` to set and then to access `if($this->a == 'a')` etc...

Comment: you need to return something in function combine() and store than making some variable in other two functions

Comment: @BlueRose Ah, so that's the only way this can be done?  creating the variables outside of the functions inside the class then the other two will use `$this->variable` to access it.  having `combine()` inside both functions so each time one of them is called, the variables stored outside of the function will change.